# Trying to see the contents of an online SQL Server table called "test"

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to see the contents of an online SQL Server table called "test". The name of the project is dbMVC. The SQL Server table is called test. It has 5 columns: idt, datetime, col1, col2 and col3. The class file contains all of these elements. The connection string is working and named "DataContext".

The dbContext file links the connection string with the class object. The controller puts it all together getting ready for the view View1, which should print out the contents of the table: "test".

I am getting a 404 error:

> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

`View1.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<dbMVC.Models.test>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h1>View</h1>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h2>@item.idt @item.datetime  @item.col1 @item.col2 @item.col3</h2>
}
```

`TestDataController.cs`:

```
using dbMVC.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace dbMVC.Controllers
{
    public class TestDataController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /TestData/

        private DataContext db = new DataContext();
        public ActionResult DataIndex()
        {
            var dataout = from test in db.Data1 select test;
            return View(dataout);
        }
    }
}
```

`DataContext.cs`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using dbMVC.Models;

namespace dbMVC.Models
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        //enables CRUD
        public DbSet<test> Data1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Data.cs`:

```
namespace dbMVC.Models
{
    public class test
    {
        public int idt { get; set; }
        public string datetime { get; set; }
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public string col3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to get to?

Comment: www.mysite.com/testdata/view1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the server you are trying to access has granted you permission to do so. It is fairly common this happens to people setting up connections.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the default routing, the path you need to hit should be `testdata/dataindex`. Then either rename your view to `dataindex.cshtml` or change your Action to specify the view:

```
return View("view1", dataout);
```